# TooltipLabel issue with BarChart3D

Tags: plotting, bugs

**Bug introduced in 11.3. Fixed in 13.2.0 or earlier.**

---

Need a workaround so I can plot a tool tip that provides the bar height and in the same tool tip also gives the parts of the dataset that created the bar in `BarChart3D`.  I have tried `LabelingFunction -> TooltipLabel`, but today it only works on small datasets, but when the data is larger (1600+ plotted points) it fails to work.  This is a bug in 11.3 confirmed by MMA support.  So I'm wondering if the geniuses here on MMSE can provide a good solution until this gets fixed in the code.

```
dataLabels = Partition[Round@RandomReal[{0, 100}, {20, 4}], 4];

barheight = Partition[Flatten@RandomReal[{0, 1}, 20], 4];

TooltipLabel[value_, {row_, column_}, {{rowLabel_}, {columnLabel_}}] :=
   Placed[Row[{value, ", ", {dataLabels[[row, column]]}}], 
   Tooltip];

plot = BarChart3D[barheight, ChartLayout -> "Grid", ImageSize -> 200, 
           BoxRatios -> {7, 7, 5}, 
          Method -> {"Canvas" -> None}, Boxed -> False, 
          Ticks -> {None, None, Automatic}, ViewPoint -> {0, -1.5, 1.5}, 
          BarSpacing -> None, 
              Background -> White, Lighting -> "Neutral", Axes -> False, 
          LabelingFunction -> TooltipLabel]
```

The code above works on small charts like this example but at some point the tooltip disappears as the plots get larger.  I need a solution that works on a 2k size data set.    Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increasing the points to the number suggested by the OP

```
dataLabels = Partition[Round@RandomReal[{0, 3000}, {20, 4}], 4];
barheight = Partition[Flatten@RandomReal[{0, 5}, 20], 4];
TooltipLabel[value_, {row_, column_}, {{rowLabel_}, {columnLabel_}}] :=
   Placed[Row[{value, ", ", {dataLabels[[row, column]]}}], Tooltip];
plot = BarChart3D[barheight, ChartLayout -> "Grid", ImageSize -> 200, 
  BoxRatios -> {7, 7, 5}, Method -> {"Canvas" -> None}, 
  Boxed -> False, Ticks -> {None, None, Automatic}, 
  ViewPoint -> {0, -1.5, 1.5}, BarSpacing -> None, 
  Background -> White, Lighting -> "Neutral", Axes -> False, 
  LabelingFunction -> TooltipLabel]
```

gives

> [image: Blockquote]